# Book recommendation about languages from the linguist's perspective

Tags: discussion, resources

Not sure if book recommendations are allowed, but I'm looking for a reference book that contains details about a wide variety of languages, written for linguists. For example, let's say I wanted to know the word order of Polish, or the written script of Urdu, or the basic grammar of Korean, etc. A book that contains a reasonable summary of the nuts and bolts of most languages. Not as a resource for learning the language, just as a reference for an overview of the language.

Comment: Bernard Comrie's classic [_The World's Major Languages_](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_World_s_Major_Languages.html?id=-mcvAAAAYAAJ) has articles on around 50 languages, each chock-full of information.